# TeamCity build notifier application for Linux?

Tags: linux, continuous-integration, teamcity

### Background

I use TeamCity for my continuous integration server. As part of my development environment, I like to have a build notification application running so that I am immediately aware of when a build broke. TeamCity ships with several notifiers out-of-the-box including plug-ins for Visual Studio and Eclipse as well as email, jabber, and Windows System Tray application notifiers.

### Requirements and Constraints

The specific requirements and constraints of my environment make it such that none of the built-in notifiers meet my needs:

- The VCS and CI servers are on a network that is not connected to the Internet (thus no Twitter or Jabber notifiers)
- There is no email infrastructure on that network either (thus no email notifier)
- There is no Jabber or messaging infrastructure (thus no Jabber notifier)
- I do my development on a network separate from where the VCS and CI servers are and ferry the code over to perform my check-ins. ( Thus no IDE notifier)
- I'm running Linux (thus no Windows System Tray notifier).
- I do not want to have to add any additional communications infrastructure (e.g. Jabber or  email) to facilitate a notifier
- I do not want to run a Windows machine (VM or otherwise) just to use the system tray notifier.
- I am running X in Linux, so a graphical client is acceptable (and desirable)
- I'm running Ubuntu 10.10 on the machine I where I would like to receive notifications and TeamCity v6.0.3

### Question

**Are there any build notifiers for TeamCity that work in Linux that do not require anything more than a Linux desktop and to have communication with the CI/Build server itself?**

I would ideally like to have something like the system tray notifier or a stand-alone GUI application that would provide me notifications.

Comment: @EranHarel no, I never found a solution that met my requirements/constraints. The RSS feed is the best "lead" I got.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a TeamCity notifier which would do this but perhaps you can leverage the RSS feeds from TeamCity?

Comment: A Linux desktop RSS feed reader may work decently. I'd have to make it check more frequently than you would a normal website. I wonder if they color their feed posts at all based on the status ....

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about other TeamCity notifiers (which would fullfill your restrictions).

But, if you have a Linux box, it is not difficult to setup a simple Jabber server (like jabberd 1.4 or jabberd 2). They should work without problems, though personally I tried only jabberd 1.4.
There are some more OSS XMPP/Jabber servers: http://www.saint-andre.com/jabber/jsc/

After that you'll be able to setup a couple of Jabber accounts from any Jabber GUI client (for TeamCity and yourself).

I think, this would be the easiest way for you.

Comment: While I agree that setting up a Jabber server on a Linux box isn't difficult, it's an explicit requirement for me not to have to setup any additional communications infrastructure just to support a build notifier.